# Calculating derivative at values in a list

Tags: r, derivative

I have a function, say f = f(x)

I have a list of values of x. q is just the data list

I wish to create a new list with values of f'(x) for all x values I have.

```
f = sqrt(x)
xt = ts(q)
count = length(xt)
f' = rep(0,count)
for (k in 2:count){
    f'[k] = D(f,"x")[k]
    }
```

This isn't working. Could someone please help?

Comment: Btw f` does not seem like a legit name. Change it and rerun the code?

Comment: Defining function f is not working, it's giving out an error message.

Comment: *R* does not get what f` stand for. Change the name to `f_der`

Comment: Did that. Didn't help. Because f is not defined properly, the loop doesn't procceed

Comment: Change the code, and add `x`, `q` as well as the error it is giving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
  d<-D(substitute(sqrt(x)),"x")
x<-1:5 #if u have a list use unlist example x<-list(1,2,3) x<-unlist(x)
eval(d)
```

The trick is that you have to pass an expression, if you do something like

f=sqrt(x), R will compute the value of sqrt(x) and if you don't define x (and in any case is not what u want).
You have to pass an expression and substitute just don't evaluate.
You want to eval after the derivative is computed.

Comment: This doesn't work for the list. I need x = all values in the ts.